# 3D pipe drawing in Python/Matlab

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working on this paper in which I'm simulating Vibration of Pipe Elbows with FEM, originally I made this in Matlab but then I migrated to Python.

Basically my data is stored in nodes, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOWTO.png), where I have the coordinates of the node on the centerline of the pipe and the coordinates of the centerline of the cross-section.

I would like to use these data to make a smooth surface plot [like this other one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05eZC.png) from [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tws.2020.107243). But I'm not really sure about what function of Matplotlib I could use to work this out.

Somebody has an idea for this?

Comment: I would use a different kind of tool, e.g., Blender or, probably more topical, Gmsh

Comment: A cursory look at the bibliography of the linked paper points to an usage of Ansys to realize the images, rather than something obtained using a general programming language.